# Do devices reconnect if IoT Hub restarts?

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-hub

I'm wondering if devices connected to an IoT Hub reconnect to it (or if they just crash) if IoT Hub for some reason stops and starts again after a while. E.g. if the subscription runs out.

I've been trying to test this but can't find out how to stop my IoT Hub and restart it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to stop an IoT Hub. As mentioned [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/iot-hub-devguide-quotas-throttling/), the IoT Hub will accept messages beyond the limits for a while, but at some point it will refuse the messages (i.e. returns an error). This is something you can detect in your device's code that is sending the events.

Comment: Reginbald does have a good point that when the subscription expires, IoT Hub will be suspended.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to setup a test account with small balance, when this account is overdue the IoT hub status is stopped. You can test under this situation.

And for test purpose to stop IoT hub for a while you can vote up [this suggestion](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/321918-azure-iot/suggestions/10433790-iot-hub-needs-enabled-disabled-option).